# Rename values not contained in a specific list

Tags: python, pandas

I need your assistance in completeing the following task:

I would like to change all values of a column in pandas to 'others' expect specific 10 values.

Example :

```
Column a
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
6
6
6
```

List_not_change = ['1','2','3']
rest change to 'other'

Expected Result :

```
Column a
1
2
3
other
```

Comment: You cat try this `df['Column A'].apply(lambda value: value if value in list_not_change else 'other')`

Comment: Not so efficient...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for mask and replace by mask in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#if values are integers
List_not_change = [1,2,3]

#if values are strings
#List_not_change = ['1','2','3']

df.loc[~df['Column a'].isin(List_not_change), 'Column a'] = 'other'
```

Comment: Go jezzy! Go jezzy!